# Construct a basis of the linear subspace $U= \{ (x_1,x_2,x_3) \in \mathbb{R}^3|x_1+x_2-x_3=0\}$ and complement it to a basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: linear-algebra

The following exercise is given:
Construct a basis of the linear subspace $U= \{ (x_1,x_2,x_3) \in \mathbb{R}^3|x_1+x_2-x_3=0\}$ and complement it to a basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$.

To this exercise I've got the following solution:

$$
\begin{split}
 0 &= x_1+x_2-x_3 \\
 0 &= 1 \cdot x_1+ 1 \cdot x_2- 1\cdot x_3 \\
\ \\
\tilde{u}&= (1,1,-1)^\top\\ 
n &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}(1,1,-1)^\top\\
e_x &= (1, 0, 0)^\top\\
e_y &= (0,1,0)^\top\\
e_z&= (0,0,1)^\top\\
\ \\
\tilde{e_1} &= e_x - (e_x \cdot n) \ n\\
\tilde{e_1} &= (1, 0, 0)^\top - \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} \cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} (1,1,-1)^\top\\
\text{with } (e_x \cdot n)&= \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} \text{ because } (1, 0, 0)^\top \cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}(1,1,-1)^\top = \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\\
\ \\
\tilde{e_1} &= (\frac{2}{3}, -\frac{1}{3}, -\frac{1}{3})^\top\\
e_1 &= (2,-1,-1)^\top\\
\ \\
\tilde{e_2} &= e_y - (e_y \cdot n) \ n\\
\tilde{e_1} &= (0, 1, 0)^\top - \frac{1}{3} \cdot (1,1,-1)^\top = (-\frac{1}{3}, \frac{2}{3}, \frac{1}{3})^\top\\
e_2 &= (-1,2,1)^\top\\
\ \\
\mathbb{R}^3 &= \text{span}\{e_1, e_2, n \}
\end{split}$$

We did this at university, but the tutor wasn't explaining it well. 
What is $n$? What is $\tilde{e_1}$ and $\tilde{e_2}$?
Could somebody please enlighten me about this?

Comment: Do you mean orthogonal complement ? Or just extend to a basis ?

Comment: why do the question in such a complicated way ?

Comment: I know why the tutor didnt explain it, cause he doesnt understand it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall that a basis of a space is a collection of linearly independent vectors in the space that span the space. As you noted, U is 2 dimensional with a 1 dimensional orthogonal complement, so to begin we just need to find 2 linearly independent vectors in U (we get that they span automatically from U being 2 dimensional).

We just take $(1,0,-1)$ and $(0,1,-1)$ to be our 2 vectors. Its obvious they are in U and linear independence follows by quickly checking that $(a,b,-a-b)=0 \implies a=b=0$.

When you said complement it to a basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$, im assuming you just meant extend it to a basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$? In this case we just take any vector outside of U, as this cannot be dependent on our other 2 vectors, and so must give 3 linearly independent vectors in a 3 dimenional space, and hence a basis.

For this 3rd vector just take $(1,0,0) \notin U$.

Comment: Thank you, this helps a lot. Yes, I meant extending it to such a basis. I still would like to ask: what you mean by that U has a 1-dimensional orthogonal component?

Comment: I assume this also has something to do with the vector $n$ he introduced. I recall him saying about that $n$ is the normal to something... I assume the plane which is spanned by the other two independent vectors in U you were talking about?

Comment: Yes, im using the standard inner product in $\mathbb{R}^3$ - the dot product. Like you said, U is a plane, so the orthogonal complement of U (That is all the vectors such that they have 0 inner product with any of the vectors in U) is a 1 dimensional subspace spanned by the normal vector to the plane.

Comment: One could also simply take for the third basis vector the normal $(1,1,-1)$ given in the defining equation of $U$.

Answer (score 2):

Say $v\in U$, then $$v = (x_1,x_2,x_3) = x_1(1,0,1)+x_2(0,1,1)$$

So $a= (1,0,1)$ and $b= (0,1,1)$ make the basis of $U$. Then take $$c = a\times b = \left(%
\begin{array}{ccc}
  i & j & k \\
  1 & 0 & 1 \\
  0 & 1 & 1 \\
\end{array}%
\right) = (-1,-1,1) $$
which spans the orthogonal complement of $U$. So $a,b,c$ make the basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$.